# Getting objects via ManyToMany relation after filter in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

I have these models:

```
class Notebook(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63)
    notebooks = models.ManyToManyField(Notebook, related_name='tags')
```

and I'm trying to find all Notebooks that have two particular tags (I can probably deduce the rest of the query if I can get two tags working)

I'm defining a query for the two tags with:

```
            query = Q(name__iexact='dna') | Q(name__iexact='notebook')
```

and I can filter the pertinent tags with:

```
Tag.objects.filter(query)
```

But I'm seeking all the Notebooks that have these tags. In SQL I would do a JOIN but the ORM method `select_related` apparently doesn't work with ManyToManyField

Answer (score 1):

Under [spanning multi-valued relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships), the documentation says:

> Successive filter() calls further restrict the set of objects, but for **multi-valued relations**, they apply to any object linked to the primary model, not necessarily those objects that were selected by an earlier filter() call.

The examples following then show `filter` being chained when querying a m2m relationship. So based on the models listed in the question, you can create a query and then loop through the tags to keep adding a `.filter(tags_name__iexact=tag)` to the query object

```
        tags = ['dna', 'notebook']
        q = Notebook.objects
        for tag in tags:
            q = q.filter(tags__name__iexact=tag)
        return q
```

I initially thought the approach would involve constructing a big Q object with a reduce lamba but chaining works.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter using the related_name:

```
Notebook.objects.filter(Q(tags__name__iexact='dna') | Q(tags__name__iexact='notebook'))
```

OR

```
tags = ['dna', 'notebook']
Notebook.objects.filter(tags__name__in=tags)
```

Comment: Thnaks but that's an OR query. I'm trying to find all notebooks that have all the specified tags e.g. 'dna' AND 'notebook;